# How to Initialize a variable from mySQL using node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I feel like I'm making an obvious mistake here. I'm just trying to initialize a variable in the constructor of an object:

```
var Lobby = function(io, dbConnection, lobbyName) {
  this.connectedPlayers = {};
  this.seatedPlayers = [];
  for (var i=0;i<this.NUMBER_OF_TABLES;i++) {
    this.seatedPlayers[i] = [];
    for (var j=0;j<this.PLAYERS_PER_TABLE;j++) {
      this.seatedPlayers[i][j] = null;
    }
  }
  if (lobbyName == "lobbya") {
    dbConnection.query("SELECT id, username, rating FROM players WHERE id < 0 order by id desc;",
    function (error, results, fields) {  
      for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
        var computerPlayer = new Player(results[i]["id"],results[i]["username"],results[i]["rating"]);
        this.connectedPlayers[results[i]["id"]] = computerPlayer;
        this.seatedPlayers[i+4][1] = computerPlayer;
        this.connectedPlayers[results[i]["id"]].setSeatedAt(i+4);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I run this, connectedPlayers is undefined. (I assume because it's out of scope, since I'm within the function processing the results. So how do I initialize a variable outside of the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize async operations in a Javascript constructor, because constructors are, by definition, synchronous.

There are three ways to solve this problem that are common:

1) Pass in an initialized DB.

2) Lazy-load the DB when something needs it.

```
Lobby.prototype.connectPlayers = function(cb) {
    self.getConnection(err, db) {
        // getConnection will either init connection or return already inited connection
        // run stuff requiring DB connection
            cb(foo);
    });
}
```

3) Add an async initialize method which is called after it is `new`'d.

```
var lobby = new Lobby();
lobby.init(function(err) {
  // now we have it
});
```

In my eyes, lazy-load is the most efficient, since it means you aren't running anything more than you need. Some `Lobby` may not need a DB connection (especially for unit tests).